# Replacing a portion of string entry

Tags: java, string, replace

I have a list of Strings, and would want to replace a few characters of the individual string entry by new string and add to the list. For eg:

```
     List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
     arrayList.add("s=1;n = 001NDA001");
     arrayList.add("s=1;n = 001NDA001.INR");
     arrayList.add("s=1;n = 001NDA001.INR.val");
     String inputValue ="CSV";
     
     for (String string : arrayString) {
      if(string.contains("NDA")) {
          arrayList.add(string.replace(string, inputValue));;         
      }
    }
     log.info("arrayList : {}",arrayList);
```

```
Current output : 
arrayList : [s=1;n = 001NDA001, s=1;n = 001NDA001.INR, s=1;n = 001NDA001.INR.val, CSV, CSV, CSV]
```

```
ExpectedOutput: 
arrayList : [s=1;n = 001NDA001, s=1;n = 001NDA001.INR, s=1;n = 001NDA001.INR.val, s=1;n = 001CSV001, s=1;n = 001CSV001.INR, s=1;n = 001NDA001.CSV.val]
```

I believe it can be achieved with regex, and I need some inputs here. Suggestions?

Comment: `string.replace(string, inputValue)` should probably be `string.replace("NDA", inputValue)`.

Comment: Here, you ask about a simple fixed string replacement. No need for a regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code for your problem

```java
for (String string : arrayString) {
  if(string.contains("NDA")) {    
      arrayList.add(string.replace("NDA", inputValue));
  }
}
```